# Is it possible write some code that forces xcode to save all or specific files?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, plugins

I'm trying to make a plugin that writes something to the .h file with a key command (⌥ + c) while I'm coding in the .m file, e.g. I'm writing a method I want to be exposed, I press my key command at the end of the line, and it automatically writes it in the .h file without me having to copy and paste it over.

If I've just made a change in the .h file and go to my .m file and use my plugin directly after, I get an error popup saying that Xcode has changes that is not on the disk yet, and then asks which version I want to use, the one on the disk or the one in Xcode.

If I'm only coding in the .m file and adding the methods and properties to the .h file with my plugin it works fine (because I haven't made any changes to the .h file manually it seems), it's only when I've just made some changes myself to the .h file and go back to the .m file and use my plugin directly after that I get an error.

If I'm changing something in the .h file and then press ⌘+s and go over to my .m file and use my plugin it also works as intended because I force it to save whatever is in the .h file now. But pressing the ⌘+s command from the .m doesn't help my case, so it seems to only save the current file you're working on, be it the .h file or the .m file.

So my question is, is it possible to make some lines of code which forces Xcode to save all files (or just the .h file if that's possible, I have the, I have the filename and the path), so I'm sure Xcode and the data on hard disk matches up before the plugin makes any changes to what is already on the hard disk?